# How to call mirage server before application starts in StencilJS

Tags: stenciljs, miragejs

I am working on a `StencilJS` project where I have to use `MirageJS` to make fake API data.

How to call server before StencilJS application loads.
In react we can call **makeServer()** in the index.ts file, but in the stencil, we don't have such a file.

How can we call this to start the mirage server, Please can someone suggest the correct way.

Below is my server.ts file
mirage/server.ts

```
import { createServer, Model } from 'miragejs';
import { auditFactory } from './factories';
import { processCollectionRequest } from './utils';
export const makeServer = async ({ environment = 'development' } = {}) => {
  console.log('started server');
  return createServer({
    environment,

    factories: {
      people: auditFactory,
    },

    models: {
      people: Model,
    },

    routes() {
      this.namespace = '/api/v1';

      this.get('/peoples', function (schema, request) {
        let res = processCollectionRequest(schema, request, 'peoples', this);
        // remove factory properties not in spec
        res.items.forEach(e => ['associatedResourceId', 'associatedResourceName', 'associatedResourceType'].forEach(p => delete e[p]));
        return res;
      });
    },

    seeds(server) {
      server.createList('audit', 20);
    },
  });
};
```

Comment: Are you creating an app or a component library?

Comment: @Thomas - I am creating the StencilJS application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with MirageJS so I might be off, but can you use globalScript (https://stenciljs.com/docs/config) and then run your Mirage server there?

Comment: You can also return a promise in your root component's [`componentWillLoad()`](https://stenciljs.com/docs/component-lifecycle#componentwillload) to delay the rendering until the promise is resolved.